# Why is my page not picking up my controller

Tags: angularjs

I am getting to understand routing and I have a simple application with a couple buttons at the top in the header area. The buttons work well and display the correct information but I've directed that one of the pages (directory.html) use the "myController" controller that I created but instead it continues to give me the curley braces and not the actual scope data. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
    <main ng-view></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/directory', {
            templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
            //since this page requires a controller
            controller: 'myController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);


angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.message = ("Hello World");
});
```

**Directory.html**

```
<p>This is my directory page.</p>
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

**Header.html**

```
<div id="menu-bar">
    <h1>My Sample App</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#directory">Directory</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js file is invalid.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/directory', {
            templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
            //since this page requires a controller
            controller: 'myController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

}]);

angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.message = ("Hello World");
});
```

You have placed your controller inside the config module...

Comment: Thalaivar, thanks for your reply. I modified my code based on your response and modified the JS in my original post. Unfortunately now the buttons do not work.

Comment: Never mind, got it. It was a duh on me. Thank you !!